# Running slow async task in the background in Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I want to do the following:

```
while True:
  if condition():
    perform_task_in_background();
  perform_other_task_without_interruption();
```

What's the best way to do this with asyncio? In particular, I want perform_other_task_without_interruption() to run without interruption when perform_task_in_background() is running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the task in a separate thread using [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor):

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

loop.run_in_executor(executor, perform_task_in_background)
```

This example runs the task in threads, but you can also run it in a separate process (i.e. dedicated cpu core) if performance is crucial. See [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) for that.